# change an element back after eventlistener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have an element `(const catchMe = document.getElementById("catchMe")` that "runs away" from the mouse, it does so by calling a "move" function `catchMe.addEventListener('mouseenter', move)` that simply sets it's css style.top etc. at random points on the page (the 'running' is done through css transition as well).

What I'm trying to do is to have the catchMe element move back to it's original position a few seconds after `mounseleave`, and so I added an eventListener `catchMe.addEventListener('mouseleave',startPosition)` that rewrites it's original css but has a setTimeout in it.
But the problem is that if I mouseEnter again it won't wait a few seconds till it calls `startPosition`, since the previous mouseLeave is still active,

So the question is, is there a way to cancel the 'old' mouseLeave upon a new mouseEnter? Or is there an easier way to go about this in general?

I'm using simple javascript

Comment: You should add a [mcve] to the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const catchMe = document.getElementById('catchme');

let timeout;
catchMe.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
});

catchMe.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event){
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#888';
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#catchme {
    background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='catchme'>Catch me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe you mean like this? I put `clearTimeout()` on mouseenter

Comment: *note: timeout must declare on global_scope(Outside Function) for use at multi function

Comment: perfect, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

***The best option that I could suggest you is to relay on the CSS classes.***

Example :

***CSS***

```css
#catchMe{
position: absolute;
}

.Move{
top:20px;
}

.startPosition{
top:0px;
}
```

***JavaScript***

```js
catchMe.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
catchMe.classList.add('Move');
catchMe.classList.remove('startPosition');
})

catchMe.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
catchMe.classList.remove('Move');
catchMe.classList.add('startPosition');
})
```

Hope this method can help you out.